# Formularios Django: Convertir campo 'select' de clave foranea a campo 'Search'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Utilizo Django 3.0.4 y Python 3.7.3

Tengo el tipico formulario de un modelo donde tengo un campo que apunta a otro modelo.
El campo en el formulario originalmente utiliza el widget **forms.Select**, una lista desplegable con la data del otro modelo para seleccionar uno.

Al principio bien, pero ésto ya no me es útil porque tengo muchos datos y es muy complicado conseguir entre una lista desplegable de mas de 100 registros.

Quisiera cambiarlo a algún tipo de campo 'search', de modo que en vez de seleccionar el dato de una lista interminable, mas bien pueda colocar en el campo el nombre o parte del nombre de la data que quiero buscar en el otro modelo, para no tener que usar la ya muy incómoda lista desplegable.

El código de mi forms.py es el siguiente:

```
class model2_forms(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = model2            

    fields = [
        'clave_id',
         ]

    labels = {
        'clave_id': 'Data modelo relacionado',
    }

    widgets = {
        'unit_id': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}), #He comentado este mientras hacía las pruebas en mi código
    }
```

Así está el html de la plantilla para el formulario:

```
{% extends "plantilla_base.html" %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block content %}
<div class="form-group" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="{{form.clave_id.name}}">{{form.clave_id.label}}</label>
                {% render_field form.clave_id class="form-control" %}
            </div>   
        </div>     
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">
                    Save <i class="fas fa-check">   </i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

En la plantilla intenté usar `{% render_field form.clave_id type="search" %}` y `{{ form.clave_id|attr:"type:search" }}` de **django-widget-tweaks** para ver si cambiaba el tipo de widget a alguno de texto de tipo **search** pero nunca se cambió el widget, siempre aparece el campo en modo select con la lista desplegable.

Alguna idea??

Comment: La librería [*django-widget-tweaks*](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/), es para personalizar los campos de formulario en el mismo HTML sin tener que tocar "código python" (`ModelForm` o `Form`), es decir cosas simples como poner clases, atributos, filtros, etc, a los elementos en el HTML, no cosas complejas como un "search" que busque coincidencias en los elementos, etc. Dicha librería no te ayudara a hacer eso, te sugiero revisar la doc, ahí se aclara este tema. Y si quisieras hacerlo, tendrías que hacerlo con JavaScript...

Comment: Ademas el `<input>` (`type="search"`) no te funcionara, porque necesitas enviar el `id` de la instancia que se va a relacionar, y también necesitas mostrar el nombre legible del objeto para el usuario...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando Select2 https://select2.org/ en los campos que necesité pude resolverlo